# merge two lists of same type in c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, merge

I have two lists with same type as below:

```
public class ParentTutorCountModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Location
    /// </summary>
    public string Location { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Location
    /// </summary>
    public int ParentCount { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Location
    /// </summary>
    public int TutorCount { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having two methods to return parent and tutor count by location, means location is the common in both, i'm getting result of both as below:

**ParentCountResult**

```
Location       TutorCount      ParentCount
Loc1               0                1
Loca2              0                5
Loca3              0                3
```

And **TutorCountResult**

```
Location       TutorCount      ParentCount
Loc1               4                0
Loca2              2                0
Loc4               2                0
```

What i'm trying to get is:

```
   Location       TutorCount      ParentCount
    Loc1               4                1
    Loca2              2                5
    Loca3              0                3
    Loc4               2                0
```

I have tried Union, join but not getting desired result. please help me.

Comment: You'll need to use `Concat`, `GroupBy()` and `Sum()`. However, it seems a bit suspicious that these functions are guaranteed to return 0 for one field. It seems as though they shouldn't both be using the same return type.

Comment: Kindly share what you have tried.

Comment: @Rob, could you please provoide sample code how?

Comment: @Atk, i have mentioned i've used Union and Join.

Comment: @downvoters please comment

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @Rob, here is what worked for me

```
var result = parentCount.Concat(tutorCount).GroupBy(r => r.Location).Select(r => new 
{  
   Location = r.Key, 
   TutorCount = r.Sum(rr => rr.TutorCount), 
   ParentCount = r.Sum(rr => rr.ParentCount) 
});
```

First concat the two lists, group by and sum.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it with union and getting the same output.

```
 var resultq1 = from a in parentCount.Union(tutorCount)
                           group a by a.Location into temp

                           select new
                           {
                               Location = temp.Key,
                               TutorCount = temp.Sum(rr => Convert.ToInt32(rr.TutorCount)),
                               ParentCount = temp.Sum(rr => Convert.ToInt32(rr.ParentCount)),
                           };
```